# What does it mean for a type system to be "inconsistent"?

Tags: logic, proof-theory, type-theory

[This paper](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01094195/document) on the calculus of inductive constructions states:

> The need for an infinite hierarchy of universes comes from the fact that the more naive system where we have only one sort $\mathsf{Type}$ of type $\mathsf{Type}$ is **inconsistent**.

What does it mean for a type system to be "inconsistent"? 
Does it mean that one object can be typed in multiple ways?

Comment: Typically it means that every type is inhabited; think of it as a type-theoretic principle of explosion.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine, so basically it means you have a way to get a function from an inhabited type to any arbitrary type? (how could you possibly get such a general function?)

Comment: The main example I know of is [Girard's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_U#Girard's_paradox), which arises for certain formulations of polymorphic type theory.

Comment: @user83014 Yes and no. It means that you can construct a closed term for any type. Often this can be reduced to constructing a closed term of a $\bot$ or $\mathsf{Void}$ type for which there is the rule, corresponding to the principle of explosion, that may be written like $\dfrac{\Gamma\vdash t:\bot}{\Gamma\vdash \mathsf{absurd}(t):T}$ for any type $T$. This will result in a closed term for any type. Given a rule like this, then having a term of a function type from a (constructively) inhabited type to any type is equivalent to what I stated.